# cant get out do While Loop

Tags: java

I have a problem with my code, where I cant get out of a loop. I have to create a program where i input a number and then i am asked to enter an odd value greater than the first value. For example i input 12, and in order for the program to end, i have to input 13, 15, 17 or any odd number greater than 12. If i enter a number even it tells me to try again. if i input a odd number(3) lower than the value (12) it tells me that i have to input a value greater than 12.

i know how the logic to this program works, well i think i am doing it right. 
Ok when i run the program and input 12 for example, and then input the next value (15), it does what it is supposed to do. but i input 12 and then input a number lower than 12 like 3 or or a even number instead of a odd value greater then 12, it keeps telling me to try again, even i input a good value like 15. Basically the loop keeps repeating it self over and over again.

I am new to java so its hard for me to figure out what im doing wrong. i have researched while loops but  i can't figure out how to get out of the loops.

this is my code so far.

```
import java.util.*;

public class bonus2 {
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Please Enter any number: ");
    int theValue = getBigOddValue(0);
    System.out.printf("The Value gotten was %d. \n", theValue);
}

private static int getBigOddValue(int value) {
    value = input.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("Enter an odd number greater than " + value + ": ");
    int cutoff = input.nextInt();
    int val = cutoff;
     while (val % 2 == 0){
        System.out.printf("The number is even. Try again: ");
        input.nextInt();
     }
     while (val<value){
        System.out.printf("The number must be greater than " + value
                + ". Try again: ");
        input.nextInt();
    } 

    return cutoff;
}
```

SAMPLE RUNS (how my runs should look like).

```
**Call (and return displayed):**
theValue =getBigOddValue(14);
System.out.printf("The value gottenwas %d.\n",theValue);


**Machine-user interaction of above:**
Enter an odd number greater than 14: 2
The number is even. Try again: 28
The number is even. Try again: 11
The number must be greater than 14. Try again: 3
The number must be greater than 14. Try again: 18
The number is even. Try again: 9
The number must be greater than 14. Try again: 19
The value gotten was 19.
```

Comment: If you have deleted your code you have made this question invalid too. If security is important to you, keeping a clean and meaningful website is import for SO participants. Delete your question.

Comment: i cant, because it says that it already has answers.

Comment: Write to meta.stackoverflow.com. They can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign `input.nextInt()` to your value variable.

```
while (val % 2 == 0){
    System.out.printf("The number is even. Try again: ");
    val = input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: OMG, that was all. Wow. such simple things. Thank you guys for your help. ^_^ Thank you so much.

Comment: @ThomasW  -  ok so now every time number bigger than the 'value' (18) , even it is even, i get the final output as : The value gotten was 18. If its 18 it is supposed to be detected as a even number but that is not happening.. any suggestions? – If you could run the code, and run the Sample Run, it will help you understand what i am talking about.   Once i get to the part where i have to input 18, i input 18 and then it tells me The value gotten was 18, instead of the number is even Try gain: 9 and so on until i input a odd number (19).

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int getBigOddValue(int value) {
    value = input.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("Enter an odd number greater than " + value + ": ");
    int cutoff = input.nextInt();
    int val = cutoff;
     while (val % 2 == 0){
        System.out.printf("The number is even. Try again: ");
        val = input.nextInt();
     }
     while (val<value){
        System.out.printf("The number must be greater than " + value
                + ". Try again: ");
        val = input.nextInt();
    } 

    return val;
}
```

You are not changing the value of val, that's why.
And return val, not cutoff.

Comment: hey, ok so now every time number bigger than the 'value' , even it is even, i get the final output as : The value gotten was 18. If its 18 it is supposed to be detected as a even number but that is not happening.. any suggestions?